# Start tmux with cmus opend through bash script

Tags: bash, tmux

I want to open a new tmux session and window with cmus in it or, if alredy running, attach to it. At [Ubuntuusers](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/tmux) I found this Script that should do it.

```
1. #!/bin/bash
2. SESSION=main
3. tmux="tmux -2 -f tmux.conf"
4. 
5. # if the session is already running, just attach to it.
5. $tmux has-session -t $SESSION
7. if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
8.   echo "Session $SESSION already exists. Attaching."
9.   sleep 1
10.  $tmux attach -t $SESSION
11.  exit 0;
12.  fi
```

I alredy know that i can do manually it with

```
tmux new -n music cmus
```

But when I use it in the script I only get the Message

```
usage: new-session [-d] [-n window-name] [-s session-name] [-t target-session] [-x width] [-y height] [command]
```

I also tried it with new-session, but no change.  I have absolutly no clue whats the problem with the command or the script or both

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I solved this is to have a main tmux session, that programs like mutt or cmus can either start or connect to. For example, for cmus I have an alias:

```
alias cmus='monkeys -n music cmus'
```

With monkeys being the following script:

```
#! /bin/sh

name=monkeys

# make sure tmux server is running:
tmux start-server

# determine if monkeys session is running:
tmux has-session -t ${name}

# no monkeys running, create monkeys,
# if more than one argument, take it as a command to run 
# on monkeys, else just attach to monkeys
if [ "$?" != "0" ]; then
    tmux new-session -s ${name} $*
elif [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
    tmux new-window -t ${name} $*
else
    tmux a -t ${name}
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply first. But unfortunately it doesn't work here. When there is no Session it works perfektly, but when there is alredy a session I get 'create window failed: index in use: 0' back. Also my skills aren't that hight that I understand 100% of your Script. Any Idea from you?

Comment: Really? It works for me even when there is already a session. What happens when you change the elsif line to: tmux new-window -a -t ${name} $*

Comment: Also, the idea behind the script is only to check whether there is a particular session running (that is, choose between new-session or new-window). This check comes from the exit status of tmux has-session -t ${name}. The exit status is saved in the automatic shell variable $?.

Comment: Didnn't work either. Only new Error. "failed to connect to server: Connection refused
[exited]"

Comment: Today I checkt it again, I think my last comment is crap. Sry was a bit drunk yesterday. ;) Cmus was alredy running. But again it didn't work. Opening a complete new session is no problem. But it did not recognice the running session. I tried "tmux has-session -t music" and there is no responds where "tmux has-session -t test
session not found: test" shows that this session is not there.

Comment: And when I change the line new-window the script is doing something but i don't know what. I had the running session in another teminal and I think it detached and attach really quick. But in the terminal where i run the script happens nothing. I have no Idea where the problem is, there are so many possibilities.

Oh and I totally forgot, when I use the script like above i get "create window failed: index in use: 0" back. 
Sorry, I'm writing a bit confusing. ^^

Comment: I now get it. I removed the elsif part completly. And now it works. Makes sense to me, as I give the window information as an argument. But don't know why it doesn't work without the argument.